How to use Picture event in ASS format
There are different articles mentioning that ASS provides a Picture event, mentioned here and here
I have been trying to apply it like below but, without success and I couldn't find examples on the internet (not sure why)
[Script Info]
Synch Point:1
ScriptType:v4.00+
Collisions:Normal
    
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default, Noto Emoji, 16px, &H00080808, &H00080808, &HXX000000, &H00C5E71E, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 10, 10, 10, 178

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Actor, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text

Picture: 0,0:00:04.00,0:00:07.00,Default,NTP,0000,0000,0000,,emoji.jpg

Am I using it wrong, or what could be the issue ?
Note : I am using fluent-ffmpeg to burn these captions

None of the subtitle providers, and by that I mean: Libass, Guliverkli's VSFilter, xy-VsFilter, and VsFilterMod have actually implemented Picture event. There isn't an official Advanced SubStation Alpha (ASS) spec. What is commonly considered the spec is essentially the original Guliverkli's VSFilter. For example, because Windows' GDI limits font names to 31 characters (VSFilter was Windows-only), Libass (a modern ASS subtitle provider) emulates the same behavior.
Of course, there have been some typically minor changes in Libass to better match expectations, such as making blur more discrete or applying borders before transformations. These changes are documented here.
In ASSv4+, a Picture event will never be implemented. This feature is not mentioned in the ASS v4.1 RFC or the ASS v5.0 draft, and beside that, progress on these drafts is moving very slowly.
If you really want to use a picture, the only option is to use VSFilterMod, a modified version of VSFilter. VSFilterMod does not strictly follow standard override tags and has implemented its own \$img override Tag. Note that VSFilterMod may produce some visual differences compared to Libass (which is used in FFmpeg), and it is Windows-only (because it uses GDI for font measurement and rendering).
You can use it like that:
{\an5\1img(Stack Exchange Logo 200x200.png,0,0)\p1}m -20 0 l 180 0 180 180 -20 180{\p0}

Additionally, note that FFmpeg does not support VSFilter (and thus does not support VSFilterMod).
To use VSFilterMod, you should use VapourSynth, then use this VSFilterMod interface and then pipe it to x264 using the vspipe tool.
